# Prevent mobile swipe on Bootstrap carousel. data-touch="false" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to disable the Bootstrap 4 carousel swipe in my project but I'm not being successful.

It's just a simple carousel, but I'm struggling to disable this option.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a different way to obtain the same result?

In the Bootstrap documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/carousel/) it says that I can apply the data attribute data-touch="false" to disable it, but it doesn't seem to work.

I also tried the following method, which didn't work as well:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  touch: false
})

<div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-touch="false" data-wrap="false" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
...
```

both `data-wrap="false"` `data-interval="false"` are working properly.

It's just a simple carousel, but I'm struggling to disable this option.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a different way to obtain the same result?

Comment: While waiting for 4.3 to be released, what can be done to fix this? I'm on 4.2.1.

Comment: Bootstrap 4.3 is released, I suggest if you can, update to bootstrap 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer (7 feb. 2019):**

Coincidence, bumped into the same issue. Apparently it's a bug in Bootstrap, after some digging I found a [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28025) on GitHub describing this.

It's fixed and will be shipped in Bootstrap 4.3 ([see pull request here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/28046))

> **Note:** I'm not sure when Bootstrap 4.3 will be released.

---

**Edit (21 feb. 2019):**
Apparently Bootstrap 4.3 is released on [11 feb. 2019](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases), and some patches on 13 feb. 2019

Answer (score -3):

Its an old post but this might be of help to someone

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
     touch: false
});
```

Comment: This has already been stated in the question itself.