# Disable touch swiping on Bootstrap carousel on Safari

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have added the following code to the top of my Bootstrap carousel but for some reason, I cannot disable the carousel touch swiping specifically on iOS devices.

```html
<div id="infinityWarContentWrapper" class="carousel slide carousel-sync position-relative d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner w-100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use snippets for such questions

Answer (score 1):

Coincidence, Apparently it's a bug in Bootstrap.

Find your answer here [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423638/prevent-mobile-swipe-on-bootstrap-carousel-data-touch-false-not-working)